# What's wrong with my CMakeLists.txt file?

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to compile a very small program through CMake, but when I compile it and then try to build it, it gives me an error:

```
fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file '.\cm_project.dir\SharedCRT-Release\dummy.obj'
```

dummy.cpp is a source file within my project. The CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
project( cm_project )

set(SOURCES 
  src/dummy.cpp
  include/version.h
)

add_library( cm_project STATIC ${SOURCES} )

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH
  $(PlatformName)
)
```

Did I miss something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which platform are you building for? In other words, what are you passing to `cmake -G`

Comment: @RandallCook: thanks for your response. i'm running it on Visual Studio 9 2008 Win64

Comment: Seems to be working fine with Visual Studio 10 2008 (Win32). Unfortunately I don't have access to your setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess, but it could be that dummy.cpp is not compiling due to an error, and because it didn't compile, there is no dummy.obj for the linker to link, hence the linker error you see. What is odd is that there is no compiler error (or none reported).

I tried to reproduce this on my system, which unfortunately in this case is not Windows, but is a Mac on which I am targeting Unix makefiles (`cmake -G "Unix Makefiles"`). I originally kept dummy.cpp and version.h (which is #included by dummy.cpp) in the same directory as CMakeLists.txt, and it worked with no error. When I moved dummy.cpp to a src subdirectory, and version.h to an include subdirectory, the compilation broke because the compiler didn't know where to find version.h. I needed to add a line like this to tell it where it is:

```
include_directories(./include)
```

BTW, I originally had a line like `set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH $(PlatformName))` (with parentheses around PlatformName) in my CMakeLists.txt file, but I ended up with a directory called $(PlatformName) after invoking CMake. I changed it to have curly braces around PlatformName (`set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PlatformName})`) and that spurious directory was not created. Perhaps this is related to your problem.